# Send device token to PHP script via UIWebView

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am currently working on a transit web app to be used with San Diego's Metropolitan Transit System. For iOS, I was planning on using a TabBar with three items, [Home] [Favorites] [Notifications]. [Home] leads to the main page (and to any other pages), [Favorites] is where you can setup your favorite bus/trolley stops.

I was planning on having [Favorites] be where you can setup a notification to be sent to you before a bus arrives at the scheduled times provided by MTS. So for example, if a bus were to come at 10:30 and you set a notification to arrive 5 minutes before to alert you, you would get one at 10:25.

I was wanting to link the accounts with the device tokens, and I read some of the questions on here such as [Linking user account to device token for push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365766/linking-user-account-to-device-token-for-push-notifications?rq=1).

I believe it is possible to somehow link the accounts by sending the device token to the UIWebView when I login.

Hope someone can help me.

EDIT:
Below is the Obj-C code in `Home.m`

```
#import "Home.h"

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *URL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

    NSURLRequest *Request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL1];

    [webView1 loadRequest:Request1];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"1");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *deviceToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
    bool tokenIsSent = [defaults boolForKey:@"tokenIsSent"];
    NSString *newToken = [defaults stringForKey:@"newToken"];
    NSLog(@"2");
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData *usernameData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    usernameData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSString *username = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:usernameData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"3");

    if (deviceToken != nil && tokenIsSent == NO) {
        NSLog(@"4");
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url/s=%@&u=%@",newToken, username];
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSData *urlData;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if([info  isEqual: @"success"]){
            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"tokenIsSent"];
            NSLog(@"5");
        }else{
            [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"tokenIsSent"];
            NSLog(@"6");
        }
        [defaults synchronize];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"7");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First save the token to the `NSUserDefaults`

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"tokenIsSent"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Because this is done in `appDelegate`, at this point the user is not logged in yet, that's why  you need to track using something another value like in the example above `tokenIsSent` and set it to **NO** (false).

Now once the user authenticates, you can then send it to your sever and associated with that user.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
bool deviceToken = [defaults boolForKey:@"deviceToken"];
bool tokenIsSent = [defaults boolForKey:@"tokenIsSent"];

if (deviceToken != nil && tokenIsSent) {
 // it is not null , and it was not sent to PHP so send it
        if(success){
            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"tokenIsSent"];
        }else{
            [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"tokenIsSent"];
        }
        [defaults synchronize];
}
```

---

If the delgate is not being called you need to implement it:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

And make sure you assign that delegate.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Assign the delegate to WebView1
    WebView1.delegate = self

    //Perform the request
    NSURL *URL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://clovercloud.net/app/f/"];
    NSURLRequest *Request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL1];
    [webView1 loadRequest:Request1];

}
```

Comment: If you look at the comments I made in FreeGor's answer, do you think combining this answer and `NSURLRequest` that I can successfully have the account linked to the device?

Comment: @alexpja when the device registers to push services, you don't know which account is associated with that device yet, so save it first than perform the `NSURLRequest` once user is authenticated

Comment: I receive `'Use of undeclared identifier 'tokenIsSent'` in the if-then statement

Comment: @alexpja oh I assumed you would retrieve those values, check my updated answer. `success` is just a boolean to make sure the request is successful

Comment: I am inserting this into my `webView1.m`, correct? `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1` is not working and if I place this into my `- (void)viewDidLoad`, it just does it automatically

Comment: I got it to work, just not loading where I want it to load. That's my problem now

Comment: I am not sure why you are using a webview, what is the use of the webview, can you clarify?

Comment: It's a web app wrapped for iOS and support for APN.

Comment: @alexpja please update your post with that part of the code, I see in the comments you tried to pass it as a query string.. It did not work for you? also remove the `1` from `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1`

Comment: Ok we will sort this out, tell me whats not working, you get any log? does the method get called, you create a new value `newToken` ?

Comment: I get the `username` from session data, I get `newToken`, I do not get any output. I think `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` is not loading. When I place the code in `- (void)viewDidLoad`, I successfully have it sent to the server. `        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pja.clovercloud.net/SDTR/push/register.php?s=%@&u=%@",newToken, username];` becomes "success? [token] alexpja" as a notification on my phone.

Comment: I placed `@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>` and it asks if I'd like to enter `@end` after `@implementation HomeController`. Where should your code (the big stuff) go, under the `@interface` or `@implementation`?

Comment: @alexpja `@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>` should be in the interface the .h file. the code always go to .m file because you program to an implementation not an interface

Comment: OK, did that. Still does not load `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` Updated code.

Comment: @alexpja the logs dont show in the console ? `webViewDidFinishLoad` is not being called ?

Comment: It is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

The registration for push notification is done through a native app and can only be performed through a native app. For more details see answer:

[How can a web application send push notifications to iOS devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939698/can-a-webbased-app-have-push-notification)

Push notification is not associated with some kind of View.

Comment: Is it not possible to request what is currently set in a session variable such as `$_SESSION['username']` in a UIWebView and then send the username and token to a PHP script in native code such as `registertoken.php?u=USERNAME&token=TOKEN`?

Comment: @alexpja you should get device token from APNS and then you can send it from any place what you want and it's not related with PHP. See documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: I currently get the device token from the device itself and at `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` I make a `NSURLRequest` to send it to my PHP script. To verify that it works I linked it to the script I'm using to send notifications and with a GET variable `s`. Ran the app from Xcode onto my iPad, my iPhone received a notification with the device token.

Not sure what you're saying.

Comment: If user not have userID or userName I use UUID with iCloud storage for identification token.  And after user login I'm updating this row in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the device token in `NSUserDefaults`. Then you can access it from where ever you need it within your iOS app. Therefore you can pass is to the `UIWebView` when you login and link the logged in user with the device token.